# Left JOIN returning duplicate value from joined table if records does not exist in joined table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use LEFT join to join two tables but it's returning the duplicate value from the joined table
like

I have a table a which have some records like

first table
[https://prnt.sc/sx738g][1]

id
job_id
provider_id
seeker_id
created_at

38
411
180
195
2020-06-09 13:40:00

39
411
180
193
2020-06-09 13:40:

Second Table
 [https://prnt.sc/sx731i][2]

log_id
job_id
user_id
hour
minute
pay_scale
created_at

40
411
195
0
2
3.33
2020-06-10 17:54:47

Output
https://prnt.sc/sx74oz

id
job_id
provider_id
seeker_id
created_at
log_id
job_id
user_id
hour
minute
pay_scale
created_at

38
411
180
195
2020-06-09 13:40:00
40
411
195
0
2
3.33
2020-06-10 17:54:47

39
411
180
193
2020-06-09 13:40:00
40
411
195
0
2
3.33
2020-06-10 17:54:47

Expected output

https://prnt.sc/sx78ty

id
job_id
provider_id
seeker_id
created_at
log_id
job_id
user_id
hour
minute
pay_scale
created_at

38
411
180
195
2020-06-09 13:40:00
40
411
195
0
2
3.33
2020-06-10 17:54:47

39
411
180
193
2020-06-09 13:40:00
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the join keys:
`LEFT JOIN ... ON tab_booking.job_id = tab_log.job_id AND tab_booking.seeker_id = tab_log.user_id`

Comment: Yes I am doing the same ... Please see this https://prnt.sc/sx74oz

Comment: @Mannusaraswat you're not doing the same. You need to add the condition for `seeker_id` and `user_id` (in answer)

Comment: Okay let me try to change the condition but I guess its did not get my correct data

Comment: showing this https://prnt.sc/sye8ox , which is not correct according to my need

Comment: I need to fetch data according to job_id

Comment: you didn't specify your needs precisely. In the question, you want `seeker_id=195` to match with `user_id=195`, and not match with `user_id=193`, if so, you need to include `seeker_id=user_id` into `ON`